# (this).attr() stops working after jquery.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I had this code initially that worked on one project but when i decided to port it to another project, it has issues with the `$`. 
So i decided to use the `jQuery.noConflict()` method to resolve it. It resolved alright but the `.attr()` method now returns undefined.

Initial Code

```
    $(".sharebtn").click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    content = $(this).attr("data-share-content"); content_id = $(this).attr("data-share-contentid"); medium=$(this).attr("data-share-medium");
    cur_count = parseInt($("#share_count_holder_"+content_id).val());
    if(cur_count<=999){$("#post-share-count").html((cur_count+1));}
    if(cur_count>999 && cur_count<=1000000){ disp=parseFloat(Math.round((cur_count/1000)+'e1')+'e-1'); $("#post-share-count").html(disp+"K"); }
    if(cur_count>1000000){ disp=parseFloat(Math.round((cur_count/1000000)+'e1')+'e-1'); $("#post-share-count").html(disp+"M"); }

    $("#share_count_holder").val((cur_count+1));
    window.open($(this).attr("data-share-link"),"popupWindow","width=600,height=400,scrollbar=yes");
    var url = bh_url+'/admin-2/modules/blog/candor_blogger_ajax.php?action=run_share';
    $.post(url,{ content_type:content, content_id:content_id, medium:medium} ,function(data) { },"json");

});
```

After `noConflict()`

```
var bh = jQuery.noConflict();

bh(".sharebtn").click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    content = bh(this).attr("data-share-content"); content_id = bh(this).attr("data-share-contentid"); medium=bh(this).attr("data-share-medium");
    cur_count = parseInt(bh("#share_count_holder_"+content_id).val());
    if(cur_count<=999){bh("#post-share-count").html((cur_count+1));}
    if(cur_count>999 && cur_count<=1000000){ disp=parseFloat(Math.round((cur_count/1000)+'e1')+'e-1'); bh("#post-share-count").html(disp+"K"); }
    if(cur_count>1000000){ disp=parseFloat(Math.round((cur_count/1000000)+'e1')+'e-1'); bh("#post-share-count").html(disp+"M"); }

    bh("#share_count_holder").val((cur_count+1));
    window.open(bh(this).attr("data-share-link"),"popupWindow","width=600,height=400,scrollbar=yes");
    var url = bh_url+'/admin-2/modules/blog/candor_blogger_ajax.php?action=run_share';
    bh.post(url,{ content_type:content, content_id:content_id, medium:medium} ,function(data) { },"json");

});
```

The click event fires but when i log the `content` to console i get undefined. - When I restore the `$`, it works fine in the old project.
What could be my problem.

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: what happens if you just use `jQuery.attr(...)`?

Comment: I dont think that's how `noConflict()` works https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: @DelightedD0D with or without the noConflict? - let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an [IFFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and passing in jQuery  like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); // releases $ back to any other library that might be using it

(function($) { // IIFE passing in jQuery as $, inside the scope of this function $ is an now alias for jQuery
  $(".sharebtn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    content = $(this).attr("data-share-content");
    content_id = $(this).attr("data-share-contentid");
    medium = $(this).attr("data-share-medium");
    cur_count = parseInt($("#share_count_holder_" + content_id).val());
    if (cur_count <= 999) {
      $("#post-share-count").html((cur_count + 1));
    }
    if (cur_count > 999 && cur_count <= 1000000) {
      disp = parseFloat(Math.round((cur_count / 1000) + 'e1') + 'e-1');
      $("#post-share-count").html(disp + "K");
    }
    if (cur_count > 1000000) {
      disp = parseFloat(Math.round((cur_count / 1000000) + 'e1') + 'e-1');
      $("#post-share-count").html(disp + "M");
    }

    $("#share_count_holder").val((cur_count + 1));
    window.open(bh(this).attr("data-share-link"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=400,scrollbar=yes");
    var url = bh_url + '/admin-2/modules/blog/candor_blogger_ajax.php?action=run_share';
    $.post(url, {
      content_type: content,
      content_id: content_id,
      medium: medium
    }, function(data) {}, "json");

  });

}(jQuery)); // pass in jQuery
```

Comment: thanks for this..let me take it for a spin. Will post back asap

Comment: Am still getting an undefined when i alert content

Comment: What happens if you change it to  content = $(this).data("share-content"); ?

Comment: I found the bug in my html. I was placing the attribute on a different element from the click invocator. I however used your code tho for the noConflict part. Thanks